# problema con la funcion str_replace_all()

Tags: r, rstudio

Cordial saludo, he estado practicando el web scrapping desde wikipedia con la libreria rvest, y quisiera solucionar un problema que encontré al utilizar la función str_replace_all(). he aquí el código:

```
library(tidyverse)   
library(rvest)

pagina <- read_html("https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Premio_Grammy_al_mejor_%C3%A1lbum_de_rap") %>% 
  # list all tables on the page
  html_nodes(css = "table") %>%
  # convert to a table
  html_table()

rap <- pagina[[2]]
rap <- rap[, -c(5)]
rap$Artista <- str_replace_all(rap$Artista, '\\[[^\\]]*\\]', "")
rap$Trabajo <- str_replace_all(rap$Trabajo, '\\[[^\\]]*\\]', "")
table(rap$Artista)
```

El problema está en que cuando remuevo de la variable Artista los elementos entre corchetes (hipervinculos en wikipedia), al hacer la tabulación para ver el conteo por artista, Eminem se repite tres veces como si se tratara de tres artistas diferentes, igual pasa con Kanye West que se repite dos veces. Agradezco cualquier solución de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema viene desde más atrás, no de `str_replace_all`:

```
rap %>% 
  filter(grepl('Eminem', Artista)) %>% 
  mutate(n=nchar(Artista)) %>% 
  select(Artista, n)

# A tibble: 6 × 2
  Artista     n
  <chr>   <int>
1 Eminem​​      8
2 Eminem​​      8
3 Eminem​      7
4 Eminem      6
5 Eminem      6
6 Eminem      6
```

Con esto, podemos ver que tenemos la cadena `Eminem` con distintas longitudes, seguramente por algún tema de codificación o por que hay algún carácter invisible que hace que las cadenas no coincidan. Lo que puedes hacer es "normalizar" las cadenas dejando solo letras, números y caracteres de puntuación:

```
rap$Artista = str_remove_all(rap$Artista, "[^A-z|0-9|[:punct:]|\\s]")
```

Con esto, puedes aplicar tú código sin problema y obtener las 6 ocurrencias de una sola vez:

```
rap %>% 
  mutate(Artista = str_remove_all(Artista, "[^A-z|0-9|[:punct:]|\\s]"),
         Artista = str_replace_all(Artista, '\\[[^\\]]*\\]', "")) %>% 
  filter(Artista=='Eminem')

# A tibble: 6 × 4
    Año Artista Trabajo                   Origen        
  <int> <chr>   <chr>                     <chr>         
1  2000 Eminem  The Slim Shady LP         Estados Unidos
2  2001 Eminem  The Marshall Mathers LP   Estados Unidos
3  2003 Eminem  The Eminem Show           Estados Unidos
4  2010 Eminem  Relapse​                   Estados Unidos
5  2011 Eminem  Recovery​                  Estados Unidos
6  2015 Eminem  The Marshall Mathers LP 2 Estados Unidos
```

Comment: Patricio Moracho, de verdad que muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, estupenda respuesta, me ayudó muchísimo. Quisiera saber, si existe un libro o en donde puedo aprender a realizar esa normalización de las cadenas.

Comment: Usé la palabra "normalización" como una forma de explicar la acción de limpiar los datos de caracteres invisibles que no hacen al contenido, no es un tema en sí que puedas encontrar como titulo en algún libro. Lo que es importante  a la hora de tratar cadenas desde fuentes externas, saber que  existen caracteres "no imprimible" y existen también las codificaciones de texto.